# Searching for string patterns c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, search

I'm trying to search my datatable for a possible string pattern. For example I want to search the term "nin" in column A of my datatable, I want it to show all of the rows which has the pattern "nin", even if it is in uppercase or in other format. What I'm currently doing is this:

```
for(var f = 0; f < dt.Rows.Count; f++)
{
string temp = "nin";
string PositionName = dt.Rows.[f]['ColumnA'].ToString();
int tempColCount = PositionName.Length;
bool searchTerm = PositionName.Substring(0, tempColCount).Contains(temp);
}
```

But all I'm getting are rows that have the exact pattern as "nin". How do I get the other formats of the same pattern? I'm thinking something like Regex here but I can't understand the tutorials online.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/444798/242520

Comment: Instead of doing this in c#, why nor use `LIKE` DB operator and let the DBMS manage the search for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast way to search for, depending on culture an ignoring upper / lower:

```
CompareInfo compInf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo;
int compResult = compInf.IndexOf(searchInString, searchForString, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This won't be fast given the data is coming from a database and all the OP needs to do is apply a `LIKE` clause.